# Code-behind tooltips for ListView elements

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a `ListView` that is populated in code-behind, like this:

```xaml
<ListView x:Name="FruitListView">
 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="146" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
 
</ListView>
```

**Since the amount of fruits in my list changes over time, tooltips have to be created dynamically in code behind.**

```csharp
public FruitPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var Fruits = new List<string>(); 
    Fruits.Add("apple");
    Fruits.Add("orange");
 
    // Populate the ListView.
    FruitListView.ItemsSource = Fruits;
}
```

**I would now like to create tooltips on each of the ListViewItems based on the text (eg. a different tooltip for the ListViewItem that represents "apple", "orange" etc.).**

Since the `ListView`'s `ItemSource` is filled in dynamically, I assume these tooltips would also have to be done in code-behind and not in XAML.

The question is - how can I grab a `ListViewItem` to add a tooltip to it? I have tried the following code:

```csharp
foreach (var item in FruitListView.Items)
{
    // item.ToolTip = new ToolTip() { Content = "Test" };
}
```

... but "item" is a `string`, not a `ListViewItem`.

How can I "grab" each of the `ListViewItem`s in a dynamically-populated `ListView` to add a (different) ToolTip to them? Alternatively, what other control can I use to achieve this?

Comment: you already have style: `<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">`. just add setter for ToolTip there: `<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Test" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `ToolTip` from the `ItemContainerStyle` and bind it to the item and then use a `IValueConverter` ([Data conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0#data-conversion)) to provide a tool tip value based on your constraints:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <ItemToToolTipConverter x:Key="ItemToToolTipConverter" />
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
              Value="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ItemToToolTipConverter}}"/>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>

class ItemToToolTipConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
    value is string stringValue 
      ? stringValue.StartsWith("a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
        ? "Fruity begins with 'a'"
        : "Some random fruit"
      : Binding.DoNothing;

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```